# Update formula objects in R with offset function

Tags: r

I have an R formula object:

```
  R> formula.obj <- Y ~ 1 + X + offset(Z)
```

I want to get rid of offset(Z) and obtain:

```
  R> formula.obj.want <- Y ~ 1 + X
```

It seems that update function does NOT work in this scenario:

```
  R> update(formula.obj,.~.-offset(Z))
  Y ~ X + offset(Z)
```

Is there way to get formula.obj.want from formula.obj?

Comment: another possibility (although not as elegant) would be to include/exclude `offset` as a separate argument (not necessarily universal, but is allowed in `lm` and `glm`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in update. "-" is not supported for offset formulas http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/offset.html
Define another function as u did

Answer (score 1):

You can use the list structure and the language

```
> formula.obj[[3]] <- quote(1 + X)
> formula.obj
Y ~ 1 + X
> class(formula.obj)
[1] "formula"
```

Note that I did try `update`, and it did not want to include the 1

```
> update(formula.obj, .~ 1 + X)
Y ~ X
```

Comment: Because the 1 didn't show up on my machine when I used `update`

Comment: fair enough (although the actual formula is equivalent).